# Connect two set of points with a line based in the index

Tags: matlab, plot, line, matlab-figure

What I'm trying to do is connecting two sets of points (x,y based) with a line. The line should be drawn based on the index of the two sets. Meaning `set1(x,y)` should be connected to `set2(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are the same indices in both sets.

What I have so far is the following:

```
set1 = [1,2; 3,4; 5,6];
set2 = [10,20; 30,40; 50,60];
plot(set1(:,1),set1(:,2),'b+',set2(:,1),set2(:,2),'g+')
```

Displaying me the items of `set1` in blue points and the `set2` in green points. Meaning I want to plot a line between `[1,2]` and `[10,20]`

Is there any build-in function for this, or do I need to create a third set representing the lines e.g. `[ [1,2; 10,20], [3,4; 30,40], ... ]`?

Comment: Type: `plot([set1(:,1) set2(:,1)].',[set1(:,2) set2(:,2)].','r')`

Comment: @EBH thats it feel free to add this as an answer if you like

Comment: @EBH Please add as an answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to build a function, just to use `plot` correctly. If you input a matrix of x values and a matrix of y values, then `plot` interprets it as multiple series of data, where each column is a data series.

So if you reorganize you sets to:

```
x = [set1(:,1) set2(:,1)].'
y = [set1(:,2) set2(:,2)].'
```

then you can just type:

```
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

The code with our data:

```
set1 = [1,2; 3,4; 5,6];
set2 = [10,20; 30,40; 50,60];
plot(set1(:,1),set1(:,2),'b+',set2(:,1),set2(:,2),'g+')
hold on
x = [set1(:,1) set2(:,1)].';
y = [set1(:,2) set2(:,2)].';
plot(x,y,'r')
hold off
```